# Azure deployment connection string

Tags: entity-framework, azure

New to Azure and have difficulty to connect DB with webapp. I am playing with a demo project using entityframework and code first mitigation. It works as expected in my local computer and localdb. But it does not work when I try to deploy it to Azure. I use the Webapp and a SQLDatabase in Azure. Then, I try to connect them using connection string in Webconfig.

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:dritor.database.windows.net,1433;Database=dritorDB;User ID=****@dritor;Password={****};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The homepage shows up as expected. But when I try to fetch data from DB (I put some data with seed), it returns something as follows:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
 <Error>
  <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
  </Error>
```

I suspect that I made the connectionstring wrong but I am not sure. Any suggestions on how to debug in this situation would be appreciated.

Comment: The string looks correct except for the curly braces around the password.  It should just be Password=****

Comment: Haha, works like a charm. You saved my day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string looks correct except for the curly braces around the password. It should just be Password=****